# Multi Factor Authentication in Salesforce

Tags: multi-factor-authentication

I am wondering what to do in case I forget my phone and I can not use Salesforce Authenticator installed on it? Is there any other way except contacting Sys Admin in order
to he disable authentication for my account? Can I maybe use combined option - Authenticator and security keys or some other type of authentication on my laptop at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your setup, for example we allow users to authenticate with multiple authenticators (Salesforce and Google/Microsoft).

However, if they lose access to those authenticators the Sys Admin must reset the authenticator on the user.

Comment: Yeah but in that case both Salesforce and Microsoft authenticator are on mobile phone or not?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can run them on a laptop; especially with something like 1Password that will save your password and also generate your MFA code (while copying to your clipboard).

Comment: @mhdev you can also use a Yubikey or other hardware device that will satisfy the requirements. Also, feel free to mark as best answer if you think it is helpful.

Comment: You don't actually need to reset the security authenticator. An admin can just create a one time security code to log in for that day.

Comment: Kasper, that's a valid point. Although the authenticator will still need to be reset if they have lost access to that device to add it to a new one

Comment: So that means I can use both salesforce authenticator and Yubikeys AT THE SAME TIME, and it will be up to me...for example I can choose to use authenticator but when I log out and want to log in again I can use Yubikey because I can use whatever I want?